# How to null a derived object as the base class

Tags: java

The code that I want to use is

```
private void removeInstance (BaseClass b) {
    // some more code
    b = null;
}
```

`b` can be of an instance of a subclass of `BaseClass`. For example

```
public class C extends BaseClass {/* Some Code */}
```

This is what should be possible.

```
C c = new C ();
// some code
removeInstance (c);
```

However it currently does not set `c` to `null` as `c` is cast to `BaseClass` in this example.

I want to be able to set an instance to `null` from the base class in one way or another.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you want to do. What should `removeInstance` do? You know you're not touching the actual object outside of `removeInstance`, right? Pass by value, pass by reference by value kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Java is a pass by value language. Setting the `b` variable to `null` doesn't affect the `c` variable passed to that method.